# Can't wrap a jQuery object with a selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('<p>Hi Mom</p>').wrap('#foo');
</script>
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6uWP8/

My intention is to place the newly-created HTML inside of `#foo` (and keep a reference to that newly-created HTML for further calls). The [documentation for `$.fn.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) seems to tell me that I should be able to pass a selector as the argument. But the end result is no change to the document.

What is `wrap()` really doing? And how do I instead inject new HTML into the page while retaining a reference to it for chained calls? *(Hint: I'm saying that `$('#foo').html(…)` is not a solution.)*

Comment: whether http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LHGqK/1/ will do? `$('#foo').wrapInner('<p>Hi Mom</p>');`

Comment: yes I misread the question initially

Comment: [Looking at the source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/825ac3773694e0cd23ee74895fd5aeb535b27da4/src/wrap.js#L60) it doesn't seem like the function would accept a selector. I'd say the documentation is wrong :)

Comment: @FelixKling It clones the element. http://jsfiddle.net/GYsLZ/.

Comment: @FelixKling see `wrap = jQuery( html, this[ 0 ].ownerDocument ).eq( 0 ).clone( true );` in [line](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/825ac3773694e0cd23ee74895fd5aeb535b27da4/src/wrap.js#L20) so it should accept a selector but it will clone it

Comment: @undefined: Interesting. Confusing behavior IMO.

Comment: @ArunPJohny: The fact that they named the variable `html` didn't help me understanding the code ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [.appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/), it will return the newly created element

```
var $el = $('<p>Hi Mom</p>').appendTo('#foo');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wfMP7/)

Comment: That'll do. Can you explain please what `wrap()` is doing instead of what I expected it to, and what it's used for?

Comment: @Phrogz I think the best answer is to go through the [source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/825ac3773694e0cd23ee74895fd5aeb535b27da4/src/wrap.js#L60)

Comment: The source is dandy for the _what_, that's true, but not the _why_. No matter, you gave me what I really needed. Thanks.

Comment: @Phrogz in abstract for the code... `$('<p>Hi Mom</p>').wrap('#foo')` creates a new `p` element and will clone the `#foo` element and wrap the new element `p` with the clone.... but one thing is missing there the new element is not added back to the dom structure

Comment: @Phrogz see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6uWP8/2/ - inspect the dom structure to see actually what is happening

Answer (score 2):

You are wrapping the `$('<p>Hi Mom</p>')` in the div `#foo`, since the element being wrapped is not in the dom you're not going to see it. What happens is a copy of `#foo` is made and wrapped over the fragment,

```
$('<p>Hi Mom</p>').wrap('#foo').parent().prop('id')
```

will give you `foo`.
I think you were expecting the `<p>Hi Mom</p>` to be placed inside the `#foo` which would be an insert and not a wrap.

http://jsfiddle.net/6uWP8/1/

Comment: It looks like there is no way to add the content to the DOM after it is wrapped. `$('<p>Hi Mom</p>').wrap('#foo').appendTo('body')` just appends `<p>Hi Mom</p>`. So it seems that passing a selector to `.wrap` is only useful if you want to wrap already existing nodes in the document (which I don't know why I would want to do that).

Comment: `$('<p>Hi Mom</p>').wrap('#foo').parent().appendTo('body')`

Comment: Oh of course. Still a rather confusing API. I'd rather expect that `.wrap` returns the wrapper node.

Answer (score 0):

Musa is correct about the reason why wrap is not acting as you are expecting. This is in response to Phrogz comment saying

> Can you explain please what wrap() is doing instead of what I expected it to, and what it's used for?

Here is a simple example of using wrap that helps illustrate what it's doing. I added a click event that wraps #foo with an h1 tag:

```
 $('.change-size').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#foo').wrap('<h1></h1>');
});
```

When you click on the "Click Here" link, you can see the text size change because of the new h1. Makes it a little clearer that the new tag (h1) is being placed outsize of what is in the selector (#foo). See the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/gS3K8/1/

Hope that helps!